# What is the meaning of this r function %||%?

Tags: r, function

I am using a r script to make a plot using ggplot2.
The script uses this function '%||%'. What exactly is the meaning of this function?
I can't find anything on it.
Thank's

Comment: Type in `\`%||%\`` (backticks included), and you'll see that it checks if a variable is null and returns one variable or the other.

Comment: For example, one could use `(!is.null(x) && x) || y`, or you can use `x %||% y`. It's a convenience function, nothing more.

Comment: is it a dplyr function?

Comment: When you typed in `\`%||%\`` (backticks included), R tells you what package. Depending on your package versions and the order in which you load them, you might see `<environment: namespace:rlang>` or `<environment: namespace:ggplot2>` (which imports `rlang`, so visible in its workspace, too), perhaps some other package.